# Group based access to Hive Tables

Tags: hive

I am new to Hive.

Can we create a group inside Hive and ensure that only group with functional id / password is able to access the archived data?

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 1):

Privileges in `HIVE` can be handled using users, groups and roles. [HIVE Language Manual](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Authorization#LanguageManualAuthorization-Users,Groups,andRoles) has the details of the syntax and usage.

Also, if you are looking for further fine-grained security, you can make use of [Apache Sentry](http://sentry.incubator.apache.org/).